# Loading string arrays to richtextbox as columns

Tags: c#, arrays, string, richtextbox

I have two string arrays. One of them is 1 2 3 and the other one is 4 5 6. I want to load those data into a richtextbox as 1 "\t" 4 "\n" 2 "\t" 5 "\n" 3 "\t" 6. How can I do this?
Or, I load first stringarray into a richTextBox1 and the second stringarray into a richTextBox. You can explain this way too.

Here is the picture which demonstrates my purpose:

https://mega.nz/#!HRhTjawD!Ft4IAbLNrUkzYUgBSWRjvFeu9P_asPhN_MacdgD7x7U

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string builder for this. You can iterate through the array and append to a stringbuilder object and use that in rich text box.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("{0}    {1}", arr1[i], arr2[i]);
    sb.AppendLine();
}
richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have huge data in stringarray (10000 numbers). Because of that, program stopped working when I try to debug codes that you write.

Comment: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Comment: Thanks. It's working now. But I want tab space("/t") between two arrays also.

Comment: Remove the space between {0} and {1} and keep a tab space. Read about appendformat.

Comment: It is almost done. I tried sb.AppendFormat("{0} {1}", column0Array[t],"\t" + column1Array[t]); to have a tab space but ıt's not working.

Comment: See the updated answer. You need to have a tab space between {0} and {1}. sb.AppendFormat("{0}    {1}", arr1[i], arr2[i]);

Comment: It doesn't work, but I tried "{0}\t{1}" and it works. I realized that last column was not loaded into richtextbox because of i < array.Length. when I correct it i <= array.Length or i < array.Length + 1, ıt's not working. That's the last thing I want to ask you about this topic :)

Comment: If both arrays are of same length, then its not about the code. Its about the length of that textbox.